# How can I add multiple headers to a Power Pivot report?

Tags: excel, report, powerpivot

I want to develop a report using the table of data below:

| Title | FirstName | LastName | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mr | Someone | Someone else | India |
| Ms | Someone | Someone else | Australia |

Now I want to develop Excel Power Pivot report as below:

[image]

As you can see in the above report, It has multiple headers along with it's value. So how can I add multiple headers to the report?

Answer (score 0):

I came close using an Excel pivot table options.  You can compress column entries putting two (or more) objects together; this was done for Title/Location and First/Last Name.  The First/Last name are offset by though.

Excel Image:
[image: ExcelImage]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It looks closer to what I needed and I would like to use that. Can you please tell me how did you do that,and share the steps or share the excel in which you have done this?

Comment: If you click on the "ExcelImage" link of the above answer, you'll see an image of a pivot table with the title options selected (right click on title, select options).   Go to the layout tab and select show next in same column.